# Hide specific woocommerce child category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this snipet to hide child categories on Woocommerce parent category page.

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'],
                                        'include_children' => false
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children')
```

Is there anyway to hide only a specific child category from the parent category page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this function for your functionality. It may work...

```
function exclude_product_cat_children($wp_query) {
if ( isset ( $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'] ) && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {
    $wp_query->set('tax_query', array( 
                                    array (
                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array('cat', 'dog'), //product category slug to exclude
                                        'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                                    ) 
                                 )
    );
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_product_cat_children');
```